# Multiple charts sharing the same x-axis in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts

I have many signals recorded and i want to show them on a Chart using Google Charts. These signals share the same x-axis (time) but have very wide data range for y-axis (value). Some of them go from 0 to 10, while some others go from 1000 to 20000. Therefore, it's impossible to display them in the same chart.

Yes, You can use the `vAxes` property, to show them in the same chart but it limits the graph to 2 signals. And I have more than 2.

Therefore i thought about something like this: [image]

Many charts sharing the same X axis, but with dedicated Y axis. Also, the crosshair is only one for all the charts.

I've searched the Google Chart documentation, but i couldn't find anything like that.

The question is, is it possible to do it with Google Chart? Is there a function or option to do that?

Comment: you can stack the charts and hide the y labels for the non-bottom ones, but i don't think charts itself has such an option.

Comment: Ok thanks! And what about the crosshair? How to make it be unique for all the charts?

Comment: you want the crosshair too? that's going to be difficult. very difficult. if you can get the vertical line working for one chart, repost and we can figure out how to sync the line's x-axis across all charts.

Comment: At this point i think google charts are really basic tools...with way too many limitations.
There are many other tools that can do that (from default or with some tweaks). 2 examples: Highcharts: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts , dygraphs: http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html
I'll try dygraphs because highcharts is quite expensive for now

Comment: @AlbertoFontana did you stick with dygraphs or have you found anything else useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are working on object oriented solution for charts and we are thinking to make it open source. You can have a look and you can use chart skelton to fulfill your needs. Here is the link
(click on the first chart)
http://grafitome.github.io/advanced-charts.html#

Comment: in case you want any further help just let me know. Website is under construction, in case you want to enhance it or you want the source of your requirement, just drop a mail to mohit.malik@paxcel.net and source will be delivered to you.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Is it still in Alpha or i can use it for my project?

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is email your exact requirements on my email. Right now it is in beta testing phase and there will be no licensing cost for first 20 users and you are the 11th one...:)

Comment: @Mohit Malik: is project abandoned? Looks like even download link doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not biased here, but want to recommend [plottable.js](http://plottablejs.org/). Have a look at their examples section for the Synchronized Charts and Finance, as well as their tutorials section, specifically "Building flexible layouts". Their API provides a high degree of customization.